# Can I combine multiple network filesystems into one? (WebDAV specifically)

Tags: linux, file-sharing

My aim is is not redundancy but rather something akin to a file-level version of RAID-0. I have two basic goals

- to increase overall performance using multiple connection threads.
  I'm often working in a location that has a decent overall bandwidth
  but low speeds per thread.
- have a single "point of entry" on the local system that has
  the total capacity of its parts. ie, combining (4) 2.5GB WebDAV
  accounts into a single 10GB unit of storage.

Can this be achieved?

OS: Debian

Answer (score 1):

Use "Unionfs".  (See http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/project-unionfs.html)

[padding text as superuser requires a min of 30 chars for a response.]

Comment: Thanks, your answer has got me headed in the right direction but after a few days of playing, I still don't have a complete solution. In researching UnionFS, i saw discussions of aufs, mhddfs, and the newer overlayfs. Aufs specifically mentioned the ability to balance writing over multiple branches so it seemed most suitable, plus there is a fair amount of negative discussion regarding UnionFS. After mounting 4 WebDAV points i attempt to create a union with "sudo mount -t aufs -o br=/mnt/dav/dav000://mnt/dav/dav001:/mnt/dav/dav002:/mnt/dav/dav003 none /mnt/dav/union" but this errors out.

Comment: This is the error I get: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so